# Connecting to Azure Server hosted website via NAT'ed address

Tags: web-server, nat, azure, website

I have an Azure server with multiple websites published through IIS and I am wondering if there is a way to change the URL outside clients connect to without changing the name of the server.

I have my server farm connected back to my corporate network using a Site to Site VPN tunnel to a Cisco ASA. Can you do the NAT there or is there a way to do this on the Azure environment?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to archive. If you need new URL and you have DNS server, you can use `CNAME`. If you need public access, you can check the endpoint configuration on azure vm. If you want outside client to go thru your ASA, you can NAT. If you need websites sharing 80/443 port, you can add Virtual IP to cloud service.

Answer (score 0):

As Kai mentioned, if you have your own domain name you can setup a CNAME to point to your VM and your done.
If you don't and are looking to use the built in .cloudapp.net URL then it depends what type of vm you are using. If you are using the new V2 resource manager VM's then you can attach a public IP to a VM, and you can choose (within limts) what name is associated with that IP. If you are using the older cloud service based VM's then you are stuck with the name assigned to the cloud service.